Why am I getting com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10
I know this has been asking everywhere but I can't figure it out..
I have done these following things over 10 times.

Got the correct webClientId from google
Got the sha1 from gradle and added it to firebase
Updated my google-services.json

My code:
import {GoogleSignin} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: 'my_id (I didn't want to include the real id)',
});

const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
        // Attempt to sign in with Google
        const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

        // Create a Google credential with the token
        const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

        // Sign-in the user with the credential
        const userCredential = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);

        console.log('Signed in with Google!', userCredential.user);

        // Proceed with your app logic here (e.g., navigation, storing user data)
    } catch (error) {
        // Log detailed error information
        console.error("Google Sign-In error", error);
        console.log(`Error code: ${error.code}`);
        console.log(`Error message: ${error.message}`);
        console.log(`Full error: ${JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}`);

        // Display a more detailed error message
        Alert.alert('Google Sign-In Error', `Failed to sign in with Google: ${error.message}`);
    }
};


MAKE SURE YOU GENERATE THE CORRECT SHA KEY
I figured out you need to make sure you are generating the correct SHA key.
Go to:
android->app->build.gradle: look for "signingConfigs", and the file you want to target to generate your SHA key comes after "storeFile file". For example mine is "storeFile file('debug.keystore'). You will want to make note of all 4 config options.
Therefore:
cd android/app

then: keytool -list -v -keystore <your.keystore> -alias <yourkeyalias> -storepass <yourstorepass> -keypass <yourkeypass>
